# Hot module replacement does not work with some modules

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-hot-loader, hot-module-replacement

I am having a problem with react hot loader 3.

Some modules in my app get hot updated some don't. I have a folder(app) which contains all my components. In this folder i have index.js where i export all modules from the folders. In the folders i have `index.js` file which exports component itself. 
Example:

`app/test` contains `test.js`and `index.js`
    `app/test/index.js` contains `export test from ./test.js`
    `app/index.js` contains `export * as test from ./test`

And somewhere in my app i import this test app like this `import { test } from ../app`

And here where the magic shows up. hmr does not work for test.js. But if i comment line `export * as test from ./test` in `app/index.js` and i import my test component directly `import test from ../app/test/test.js` hmr works. I've been trying to fix it for 3 days now. `app/index.js` gets imported in my `routes.js` file. It's the only place where it gets imported. Only all components in `app` folder don't get hot updated everything except it works fine. I tried to reproduced it with any boilerplate and it didn't work out.

In the console i see

```
[WDS] App updated. Recompiling...
log-apply-result.js?d762:11 [HMR] The following modules couldn't be hot updated: (They would     need a full reload!)
log-apply-result.js?d762:18 [HMR] Nothing hot updated.
only-dev-server.js?2f87:49 [HMR] App is up to date.
client?e36c:37 [WDS] App updated. Recompiling...
client?e36c:37 [WDS] Nothing changed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with folders' structure. Circular dependencies failed hmr. Fixing it fixed problem.

Comment: Yeah, that fixed my code too, stupid mistake. Always check your code for circular dependencies